# How to use a variable that inside of a function of a class in another class - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, oop

I am trying to access to another variable that inside a function and also that is from another class, so I coded it in that way

```
class Helloworld:

   def printHello(self):
       self.hello = 'Hello World'
       print (self.hello)


class Helloworld2(Helloworld):
    def printHello2(self)
       print(self.hello)

b = Helloworld2()
b.printHello2()

a = Helloworld()
a.printHello()
```

However, this gives me that error: `AttributeError: 'Helloworld2' object has no attribute 'hello'`. So, what would be the simplest way to access to that variable?

Comment: Please properly indent your code, it's crucial to understanding it.

Comment: `self.hello` is set only when you execute `printHello`. If you don't call that method `self.hello` doesn't exist. In case of `Helloworld2`, that method is never called. You might want to move that to `__init__` so the property is set when the class is instantiated.

Answer (score 2):

That's because you never call `printHello(self)` that declare your `self.hello`.

To make it work you need to do:

```
class Helloworld2(Helloworld):
    def printHello2(self):
        super().printHello()
        print(self.hello)
```

**Or** move declaration of you self.hello to `__init__()` which would be more preferred way.

Answer (score 1):

You should initialise the instance of the class via the `__init__()` function, this means that when it is created, these values are set.

That would make your code look like:

```
class Helloworld:
    def __init__(self):
        #sets self.hello on creation of object
        self.hello = 'Hello World'

    def printHello(self):
        print (self.hello)


class Helloworld2(Helloworld):
    def printHello2(self):
       print(self.hello)

b = Helloworld2()
b.printHello2()

a = Helloworld()
a.printHello()
```

An alternative, with your current code is to just call `printHello()`, either at the top level, with `b.printHello()`, or within `printHello2`.  Note that in this case, you don't actually need to use `super().printHello()` as you are not re-defining that function in `Helloworld2`, though it would be required if you did.